# Python gdata progammaticLogin() - check login failure

Tags: python-2.7, gdata, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to access a Google Drive using **gdata-Python-client** package. I can get access to an account by providing authentication details (user name, password) and open a client to manipulate spreadsheets.

```
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

client=gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()

client.email=some_username

client.password=some_pwd
```

Now I want to check whether the login process was successful and I write the following piece of code.

```
try:
   client.ProgrammaticLogin()
   return True
except:
   return False
```

This code throws an exception if the login fails.

Are there other ways we can achieve this without catching this exception? (Eg. checking within an **if** clause using a return value of a method)

*As far as I know **ProgrammaticLogin()** method itself does not return any value (i.e. type(ProgrammaticLogin()) returns 'NoneType')*

If try-except is the only way to check this what is the name of the exact Exception thrown at this instant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this link multiple types of exceptions are thrown based on the error type
http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.service.html

Comment: Thanks @user2565456, this answers one part of my question. What about the other half? (other methods of checking login status), Any idea? :)